# How to create a connection between mariaDB/MySQL on raspberry Pi and Excel File on Computer in the same Network?

Tags: mysql, excel

I want to get the Data from my Database, which runs on a Raspberry Pi 3 into my Excel File. I have tried to connect via de New Query thing in Excel but it always says "Connection failed", via an ODBC connector same problem and via MySQL for Excel still Connection failed. I think I am doing something wrong because I can connect to the DB via eExplorer and phpmyadmin. Does anyone know a good way to do it or what I might could do wrong?

Thanks for any helpful answer!

Comment: Check network security issue. Port opening, network listening, firewall settings, correct ODBC driver etc.